# How to rebind datasource to Telerik RadChartView

Tags: vb.net, telerik, telerik-reporting

I am using Telerik Rad ChartView to populate sales information. I am setting the datasource using the following code  saleHistoryChart.DataSource = saleHistoryDataTable. I have a reset button & when the user clicks on it I want to reset the new data from the datatable.

I am calling the below shown populateGraph() method on both the form load & reset button click events. The datatable gets updated correctly with the new data from the database, but the chart still shows the old data. Therefore how do I rebind or reset the chart to contain the new data?

```
Private Sub populateGraph()
Dim saleHistoryDataTable As DataTable = GETDATA("SQL HERE")
saleHistoryChart.DataSource = saleHistoryDataTable
Exit sub
```

Comment: There is hardly any code, I have everything set from the designer. And just the binding source set from the .vb file.. I didn't post the SQL because it seems irrelevant to the question.

Comment: did you rebind updated data ?

Comment: Yes the datasource is set everytime the reset button is clicked.

Comment: chart.dataSource.read();
chart.refresh();

Comment: There seems to be no chart.dataSource.read() method I tried the chart.refresh() but nothing changes.

Comment: ok sorry,it was about kendo,give me 1 minute

Comment: Ok. I have added my exact method to provide more clarity. Any help is greatly appreciated as none of the docs I found on Telerik seemed to help. Pls check the updated question..

Comment: dont you use databind() ?

Comment: databind is not a member of Telerik.WinControls.UI.ChartView. Data gets set when I just apply the datasource.

Answer (score 1):

Since no solution was provided by the members of the community I added the series at runtime so that I could use `saleHistoryChart.Series.Clear()` and set the series again. Bit more code than using a direct binding. But this is the only solution I could find.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim RadChart1 As New RadChart
Public Sub New()
    InitializeComponent()
    Me.Controls.Add(RadChart1)
Dim connectionString As [String] = "Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False; Initial Catalog=Northwind;Data Source=.\sqlexpress"Dim selectCommand As String = "SELECT CategoryName, SUM(ProductSales) AS TotalSales FROM [Product Sales for 1997] GROUP BY CategoryName"
    Dim dataAdapter As New SqlDataAdapter(selectCommand, connectionString)
    Dim table As New DataTable()
    dataAdapter.Fill(table)
    RadChart1.DataSource = table
    RadChart1.PlotArea.XAxis.DataLabelsColumn = "CategoryName"
    AddHandler RadChart1.DataBound, AddressOf radChart1_DataBound
End Sub
Private Sub radChart1_DataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    radChart1.Series(0).DataYColumn = "TotalSales"
    ' assign appearance related properties
    radChart1.PlotArea.XAxis.Appearance.LabelAppearance.RotationAngle = 300
    radChart1.PlotArea.XAxis.Appearance.TextAppearance.TextProperties.Color = System.Drawing.Color.BlueViolet
    RadChart1.PlotArea.Appearance.Dimensions.Margins.Bottom = Telerik.Charting.Styles.Unit.Percentage(20)
    RadChart1.PlotArea.Appearance.Dimensions.Margins.Left = Telerik.Charting.Styles.Unit.Percentage(20)`enter code here`
End Sub
```